# navbar: keep link hover after show submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a navbar with submenus, the submenu have a background image .png, but, only 3 links have this submenu on my navbar, so, my problem is, when the menu link is hover state, and the submenu are onmouseover, the nav link lost the hover state. how to do a navbar with custom background on submenu and keep this link hover, i tried it but, i have sucess if i do it only with div, but with a unordered list is hard.

obs: below my links, when hovered have a arrow down

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#" id="empresa" class="">empresa</a>
        <div class="sub-empresa">
            <ul class="menu-empresa">
                <li><a href="historia.html">história</a></li>
                <li class="separador"></li>
                <li><a href="politica-privacidade.html">política de privacidade</a></li>
                <li class="separador"></li>
                <li><a href="#">certificações e prêmios</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="pipe"></li>
    <li><a href="produtos.html">produtos</a></li>
    <li class="pipe"></li>
    <li><a href="representantes.html">representantes</a></li>
    <li class="pipe"></li>
    <li><a href="distribuidores.html">distribuidores</a></li>
    <li class="pipe"></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="infotec">informativos tecnicos</a>
        <div class="sub-informativo-tec">
            <ul class="menu-infotec">
                <li><a href="#">generalidades</a></li>
                <li class="separador"></li>
                <li><a href="#">recomendações para instalações</a></li>
                <li class="separador"></li>
                <li><a href="#">conceitos básicos sobre condutores</a></li>
                <li class="separador"></li>
                <li><a href="#">simbologia</a></li>
                <li class="separador"></li>
                <li><a href="#">critério de dimensionamento de circuitos</a></li>
                <li class="separador"></li>
                <li><a href="#">queda de tensão</a></li>
                <li class="separador"></li>
                <li><a href="#">dimencionamento de eletrodutos</a></li>
                <li class="separador"></li>
                <li><a href="#">correntes máximas de curto-circuito</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="pipe"></li>
    <li><a href="#">eventos</a></li>
    <li class="pipe"></li>
    <li><a href="#">videos</a></li>
    <li class="pipe"></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="contato">fale conosco</a>
        <div class="sub-fale-conosco">
            <ul class="menu-faleconosco">
                <li><a href="fale-conosco.html">fale conosco</a></li>
                <li class="separador"></li>
                <li><a href="trabalhe-conosco.html">trabalhe conosco</a></li>
                <li class="separador"></li>
                <li><a href="#">seja nosso representante</a></li>
                <li class="separador"></li>
                <li><a href="#">seja nosso distribuidor</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul><!-- /.menu -->


//menu do topo
$("#empresa").mouseover(function() {
    $(".sub-empresa").slideDown(199);
});

$(".sub-empresa").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".sub-empresa").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $(".sub-empresa").css("display","none");
    });
});

$("#infotec").mouseover(function() {
        $(".sub-informativo-tec").slideDown(199);
});
$(".sub-informativo-tec").mouseleave(function() {
        $(".sub-informativo-tec").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $(".sub-informativo-tec").css("display", "none");
    });
});

$("#contato").mouseover(function() {
    $(".sub-fale-conosco").slideDown(199);
});
$(".sub-fale-conosco").mouseleave(function() {
        $(".sub-fale-conosco").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $(".sub-fale-conosco").css("display", "none");
    });
});

$("body").click(function(){
    $(".sub-empresa, .sub-informativo-tec, .sub-fale-conosco").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `div` wraping the submenu isn't necessary.

Something like this may be more simple:

```
$('.menu ul').each(function () {
    $(this).parent().eq(0).hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass('on');//for styling
        $('ul:eq(0)', this).slideDown(200);
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass('on');//for styling
        $('ul:eq(0)', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(400);
    });
});
```

not sure what your current css was, so I made some up just to see how it would work.

here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/8xu5m/

Comment: haha, i like of part "why not", but, i need follow the original .PSD file of this website. your solution works fine form me, however, if i show to you the original PSD file of this website, you will hate the designer, haha

Comment: yeah, I have no clue how it looks, but that's typically how that works, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorial:
http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

It contains a step by step explanation on how to create a nice dropdown-menu - based on unordered lists - with pure css. You should be able to solve your problem with it.

Comment: i already read this tutorial and tried it, but, not work for my case, because the submenu have a background image

Comment: works fine for me, simply add the background image directly to the link - e.g. `<li><a style="background-image:url('./images/logo.png');" href="./">Index</a></li>`
This works perfektly fine.